# Codeigniter : Using Captcha while login always storing a captcha image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using captcha while login in codeigniter. However it is logically working perfectly but on every refresh it is storing a captcha image to the folder. Can anyone suggest me how to modify the below code so that it does not store image in folder.

Storing each captcha image in folder would increase response time in case of multiple users. I have googled but could not find any solution. Please suggest. Thanks in advance
    Below is my code

```
/*--- CONTROLLER CODE --*/

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Captcha extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function auth()
    {
        $u=$this->input->post('username');
        $p=$this->input->post('password');

        $this->db->where('username', $u);
        $obj=$this->db->get('user_tbl');

        if($obj->num_rows())
        {
            $data=$obj->row_array();
            if($data['password']==$p)
            {
                $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
                $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
                if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha)
                {
                   // unlink($captcha['filename']); 
                   $this->load->view('afterLoginView');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Captcha code does not match, please try again. !');
                redirect('captcha'); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Incorrect Password !');
                redirect('captcha');      
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Incorrect Username !');
            redirect('captcha');
        }
    }

    public function index(){

        // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'/captcha_images/',
            'font_path'     => 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '140',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'word_length'   => 5,
            'font_size'     => 18
        );
        // $captcha = create_captcha($config);
        print_r($captcha = create_captcha($config));


        // Unset previous captcha and set new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $captcha['word']);

        // Pass captcha image to view
        $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];

        // Load the view
        $this->load->view('captchaview', $data);
    }

    public function refresh(){
        // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'/captcha_images/',
            'font_path'     => 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '140',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'word_length'   => 5,
            'font_size'     => 18
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and set new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

        // Display captcha image
        echo $captcha['image'];
    }
}


/*--- VIEW ----/*

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login with Captcha</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- captcha refresh code -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.refreshCaptcha').on('click', function(){
        $.get('<?php echo site_url().'/captcha/refresh'; ?>', 
        function(data)
        {
            $('#captImg').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h4>Login Here</h4>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('captcha/auth'); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" class="input" placeholder="Email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" class="input" placeholder="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Enter the code :</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" placeholder="Captcha"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="captImg"><?php  if(isset($captchaImg)){echo $captchaImg; }  ?></p></td>
            <td><p>Can't read the image? click <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha">here</a> to refresh.</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata("msg"); ?>

</body>
</html>

It is always storing images at (captcha_images/) folder.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `'expiration' => 7200` to your $config array

Comment: Many Thanks Makela :) it worked for me.  however for test I changed this to 5 seconds but surely I am going to increase this.

Comment: @Makela .. My captcha image is showing much lines on text and as per requirement only two lines with white color are required. Can you please help me here..